# How to represent a manifold living in another manifold?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I've been studying manifolds recently, and there is one thing I haven't been able to wrap my head around. It's the idea of a manifold in another manifold. Suppose that I have a 2D sphere in 3D space, and I want to place a circle in the surface of this sphere. I then have the following questions:

- How do I represent such manifold (the circle)? Is it a submanifold embedded in the 2D sphere manifold? Is it somehow a product manifold?
- Suppose that I know the exponential and logarithmic map for both my manifolds. Is there a way to obtain the exponential and log map for this new manifold (the circle in the sphere) from the original maps?

Comment: A product manifold? I don't understand your issue here. If $M\subset X\subset Y$ and $M$ is a submanifold of $X$ and $X$ is a submanifold of $Y$, then $M$ is likewise a submanifold of $Y$. Your second question is more interesting. You will need to embed your submanifold as a totally geodesic submanifold — if by exponential you mean the Riemannian exponential map.

Comment: The product manifold was the answer someone else gave me, but I thought they perhaps misunderstood the question. Totally geodesic you mean a geodesic space (i.e. the geodesic is always well defined between two points)?

Comment: Supposing my manifold is "totally geodesic submainfold", is there a way to compute the Riemannian exp map?

Comment: The definition of totally geodesic is, indeed, that any geodesic in the larger manifold starting tangent to the submanifold remains within the submanifold. So you do then just restrict the exponential map to the tangent space of the submanifold.

Comment: Imagine this simpler example: $\Bbb S^0\subset \Bbb S^1\subset \Bbb S^2$. $\Bbb S^0$ by definition is $\{-1,1\}$. Is it clear?